# Arduino LCD gives weird output

Tags: arduino

I've connected my LCD to different set of pins. It worked well with default pins, which `LCDLirary` use. But now it shows weird characters when i programmed to show something meaning full. How to solve this? (Rx pin is one of my new set of pins. But I disconnect the LCD when programming and connect only after uploading is finished. But that may not be related to the issue)

Comment: Have you checked you've assigned the pins correctly? Better to use the default..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, THAT IS THE ISSUE!!! *(if what I'm thinking is correct)*

As you said you are disconnecting the LCD while programming, the LCD will not be connected at the time when the LCD unit is initialized by the board. (Initialization begins soon after the programming, eh?). So how can the LCD show correct values without getting properly initialized??

Just reset the board after connecting the LCD. You'll have to do this in other cases also, if you are hoping to use Rx (and probably Tx) pin for some other purposes other than communicating via USB.